# Is it possible to hide the segment squares on paths in paperjs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, paperjs

When creating path elements in paperJS, the default behavior  creates small squares at the intersection of each segment. Is there a way to maintain the default blue path line but hide the squares? A property that can be used to show/hide them?

Draw a line to see an example

http://paperjs.org/examples/path-simplification/

Comment: Without using the FullySelected prop and the strokefill. I want to keep the default blue line, just show/hide the squares

Answer (score 1):

I wondered the same thing a some point but never tried to figure it out until your question.  I cant seem to find any documentation on this but it worked on jsfiddle. Try this:

```
 const scope = new paper.PaperScope();
 project = new scope.Project(canvasElem);
 project.options.handleSize = 0;
```

**Found documentation**

I believe the correct approach would be to set this value in `scope.settings`;

```
 const scope = new paper.PaperScope();
 scope.settings.handleSize = 0;
```

[PaperScope.settings.handleSize](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/#settings)